# Create lists and multiply

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to convert my radiometric counts per second (cps) back to their keV values.

It will usually (but not always) start with a list of 256 cps values read from text file and converted to double.

```
List<double> cps = rads.ConvertAll(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

I then need another list the same size with the keVs for each value. The values are spread over 0 - 3 MeV, so each element of this list will be multiplied by the value

```
double keV  = 3000 / cps.count();
```

and needs to be multiplied by it's index in the list. I think this can be done as

```
List<double> keVs = cps.ForEach(x => x * (index + 1) * keV);
```

But can I get that index value for the calculation?

Comment: `Enumerate` gives you the index.

Comment: Why are you using `ForEach`? Don't you mean `Select`?

Comment: `List<double> keVs = cps.Select((x, index) =>  x * (index + 1) * keV).ToList();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you a looking for *Linq* [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) which provides index as well as value:

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<double> keVs = cps
  .Select((x, index) => x * (index + 1) * keV)
  .ToList();
```